# Filter DataSet by email address with LINQ query not working

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have this SQL query for filtering DataSet result by email address:

```
SELECT t.[ID]
  ,s.[Email]
  ,[StockSymbol]
  ,[StockID]
  ,[SubscriberID]
  ,[IP]
  ,[App]
  ,[CachedID]
FROM [NoRiba].[dbo].[Transaction] t
JOIN Subscriber s ON t.SubscriberID = s.ID
WHERE s.[Email] LIKE '%SerachString%'
```

The problem is: I want to do the same with LINQ query, But the below WHERE clause is not working:

```
 var transactions = (
         from t in db.Transactions
         join s in db.Subscribers on t.SubscriberID equals s.ID
         orderby t.TimeStamp descending                    
         select new { t.TimeStamp, t.StockSymbol, t.StockID, t.SubscriberID, t.IP, t.App, t.CachedID, s.Email })
         .Skip(param.iDisplayStart).Take(param.iDisplayLength);

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(param.sSearch))
{
    transactions = transactions.
        Where(s => s.Email.Contains(param.sSearch));
} // This code returns zero rows after executing and searching with any string.
```

Can you point me out please where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: Try s.Email.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.toLower()). Contains is case sensitive if I am not wrong

Comment: @SergueiFedorov yeah possible. it is also possible when `param.sSearch` is containing white space.

Comment: `transactions` is in-memory collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be in character casing.

```
string search = param.sSearch.ToLower();

transactions = transactions.Where(s => s.Email.ToLower().Contains(search) || 
                s.Email.ToLower().Contains(search.Replace(" ", String.Empty)));
```

Or

```
string search = param.sSearch.ToLower().Replace(" ", String.Empty);

transactions = transactions.Where(s => s.Email.ToLower().Contains(search));
```

Comment: To add to this answer, try also Where(s => s.Email.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower()) || s.Email.ToLower().Contains(param.sSearch.ToLower().Replace(" ", String.Empty))); You might want to break it down a little more than this because it's starting to become a very long statement

Comment: yeah, it is possible coz, email id should not have any space in it. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Really Thanks for Answer, but doing ToLower() also not working.

Comment: Try printing out both to the console or in look at them in the debugger to see what the possible differences may be. Maybe a trailing white space?

Comment: also check some garbage character like `\r\n` or `\n` at the end of the string. check the the length of `param.sSearch`. @SohailxIN3N

Comment: @SohailxIN3N `Where` condition will not filter the record outside the criteria. you are already taking a part of the records using `Skip` and `Take`. the `Where` condition will be performed only those taken records. not on whole table data.

Comment: Oh Really Thanks Shell, I got where I was doing a mistake.

Comment: Most Welcome! actually i realized that when i have seen your code in updated question.